# Why are static local variable in C reloaded?

Tags: c, compilation

I have discovered an interesting behaviour about local, static variables. The compiler try to reload them every time. Below is example of code.

```
extern void extern_proc(int a, int b);
void a_proc_s() {
    static int a_var = 0;
    a_var++;
    extern_proc(a_var, 1);
    extern_proc(a_var, 2);
    extern_proc(a_var, 3);
    extern_proc(a_var, 4);
    extern_proc(a_var, 5);
    extern_proc(a_var, 6);
}
void a_proc_r() {
    static int a_var = 0;
    register int r_var = ++a_var;
    extern_proc(r_var, 1);
    extern_proc(r_var, 2);
    extern_proc(r_var, 3);
    extern_proc(r_var, 4);
    extern_proc(r_var, 5);
    extern_proc(r_var, 6);
}
```

The function `a_proc_s` will try to reload `a_var` from memory for every call to `extern_proc`. The function `a_proc_r` will use the local copy from register. **Why cannot the compiler optimise this load in the former function?**

Below is interesting fragment from x86_64 assembler. It is similar for other architectures.

```
;Fragment for a_proc_s
movl    a_proc_s.a_var(%rip), %edi
movl    $2, %esi
callq   extern_proc
movl    a_proc_s.a_var(%rip), %edi
movl    $3, %esi
callq   extern_proc

;Fragment for a_proc_r
movl    $2, %esi
movl    %ebx, %edi
callq   extern_proc
movl    $3, %esi
movl    %ebx, %edi
callq   extern_proc
```

[GCC Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/1wo991)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no way to ensure `extern_proc` will never call `a_proc_s`, modifying the static variable.

Answer (score 0):

`a_proc_s` might be called from different threads simultaneously. In this case, you'd probably expect that a different value of `a_var` is used if it was incremented by another thread (and you'd make the increment atomic).

Comment: If there are no thread specific constructs, the calls from different threads are undefined behaviour. The compiler may ignore them.